# How to count the number of duplicate entries in a column MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I have two columns in a MySQL table:

bname and count

```
 bname           count        
----------      ----------


 Blah              2

 Blah              2

 huh               3

 lol               1

 huh               3

 huh               3
```

I want something like this. I have created the count column but I don't know how to can I show it like the above example. count column is currently empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the good old group by...

```
select bname, count(*) 
from mytable 
group by bname
```

This groups the rows by the unique values, and provides the number of rows of each group.

If you want to store it in your table too:

```
UPDATE myTable updated
JOIN (select bname, count(*) as cnt 
    from mytable 
    group by bname) aggregate 
  ON updated.bname= aggregate.bname
set `count`= aggregate.cnt
```

<sub>note the backticks, I think you need that here</sub>

This should set all rows their respective repetition counts.

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e241c/1)

Comment: I am not understanding. What you gave is right I know that and thanks a lot but I don't have any values in count. And I want the values to be entered automatically. As a new enters huh into bname I want all counts for huh to increase. :)

Comment: That's it man! You're a GENIUS! Thanks a ton \m/ Hey mods give a gold batch to @ppeterka:D

Comment: When I deleted a row from the database the number didn't change automatically. What may be the problem?

Comment: @MiteshMynee You have to run this each time you update the table, or set up a trigger that tkaes care of the modification

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a query:

```
select bname,
       (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.bname = t.bname) as cnt
from t
```

This will give you the additional column on each row.

If you want to fill in the value, use `update`:

```
update t
    set count = (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.bname = t.bname)
```

This actually changes the value in the table to the count.

Comment: @MiteshMynee . . . `t` is your original table and `t2` is an alias for it.

Comment: if we use join how can the above scenario implement?